# Max weight the lid of a vacuum can hold

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vacuum, estimation

I have a box with a lid that has a mass object inside of it. I will be creating a vacuum inside of it with a $4~\mathrm{HP}$ Shop Vac that has a sealed pressure of $59~\mathrm{psi}$ and an airflow of 130 CFM. Once the vacuum is created I am flipping the box over $180 ^{\circ}$, causing the mass object inside to put its weight force pointing downward onto the lid. Is there a way that I can calculate the max weight that the lid will be able to hold before it loses suction to the vacuum and falls to the floor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the vacuum works by a pressure differential (Difference)

$\Delta P \vec{A}_{lid}= \vec{F}_{vacuum}$ where $\Delta P$ is the difference between the atmospheric pressure and the pressure of the air inside the container (which probably wont be zero, depending on your Vacuum pump, which i know nothing about)

$\vec{F}_{vacuum}$ is the force holding the lid on the container. The  Force that the object will strike the bottom will be approximately $${\Delta p_{object} \over  \Delta t } $$ where $\Delta p_{object}$ is the change of momentum of the object, (which you can calculate based off how far it fell, it has to stop when it hits the bottom), and $\Delta t$ is the time of collision, which you probably cannot calculate. Notice how the force goes down as $t$ becomes bigger- if you can slide the massive object along the side of the container instead of dropping it 180° all at once you can be sure that it wont break the lid open instantaneously.

But after that you must be sure that the weight of the object $F_g = mg$ does not exceed the force of the pressure difference. Or else it will still fall.

in short:

$$\Delta P \vec{A}_{lid} > mg + m{\Delta v \over \Delta t} $$ with $v$ being the velocity of the object when it reaches the lid

Comment: So would my pressure differential come from taking the difference between the sealed pressure that is in the vacuum pump specifications (59 psi) and atmospheric pressure (14.7 psi)? Or is the 59 psi already the difference?

Comment: You can't go below zero psi absolute. So, your local atmospheric pressure (relative to zero!) will be the largest loading. Where I live is below 13 psi on average.

Comment: @Vigs I have no idea, you'll have to figure out that by yourself. It could refer  to the pressure inside the vacuum pump itself, but i am not familiar with the technology, only the physics. The sealed pressure of the shop vac is probably with regards to the machine itself. or you could be misreading 5.9 as 59